# Index using `date_trunc` isn't used automatically

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have a table `metrics` with this index:

```
CREATE INDEX "metrics_measurementsReportedAt_metrics" ON "metrics" ("metrics", date_trunc('day', "measurementsReportedAt" at time zone 'America/New_York'));
```

The problem is that column doesn't use this index somehow:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT *
  FROM metrics
  WHERE
    "metrics"."measurementsReportedAt" >= date_trunc('day', (NOW() - interval '1 hour') at time zone 'America/New_York');
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on metrics  (cost=0.00..2101.76 rows=570 width=56) (actual time=4.383..17.626 rows=589 loops=1)
   Filter: ("measurementsReportedAt" >= date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/New_York'::text, (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 17178
 Planning time: 1.050 ms
 Execution time: 17.700 ms
(5 rows)
```

After I disable seq scan: `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on metrics  (cost=7481.69..8664.19 rows=570 width=56) (actual time=5.264..6.113 rows=589 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ("measurementsReportedAt" >= date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/New_York'::text, (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))))
   Heap Blocks: exact=266
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "metrics_resourceId_measurementsReportedAt_key"  (cost=0.00..7481.55 rows=570 width=0) (actual time=5.123..5.123 rows=589 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("measurementsReportedAt" >= date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/New_York'::text, (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))))
 Planning time: 0.289 ms
 Execution time: 6.255 ms
(7 rows)
```

query starts to run significantly faster. Why does postgres not use index here?

Comment: Does updating the statistics using `analyze metrics;` change anything?

Comment: I've tried that, of course, as `VACUUM ANALYZE` et.c. No luck!

Comment: You created index on date_trunc('day', "measurementsReportedAt" at time zone 'America/New_York'). Since you are using "metrics"."measurementsReportedAt" column in where condition, you have to create index on "metrics"."measurementsReportedAt"